# Get multiple rows in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| user_id  | name   |
===================
| 1        | marc   |

| 2        | paul   |

| 3        | glen  |

| 4        | kyle   |

| 5        | jayc |

| 6        | ken |

| 7        | raff  |
```

I have a sample table shown above. I want to retrieve the row of user id 1,2 and 5 only in a single query.

Can you guys tell me what is the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [**IN**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE user_id IN (1,2,5);
```

## [**Working Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bef/1)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from users where user_id in (1,2,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id, name
FROM   my_table
WHERE  user_id IN (1, 2, 5)
```